# How to get url id from another page by form action page

Tags: php

i have a page where i am getting the ques id and insert it in the database for that i am doing

url:  */faq/faq_question_sol.php?ques= 62*

this (  `$selected_ques=  ($_GET['ques']);`  ) is working properly in the *faq_question_sol.php* but the *answer_submit_process.php* does not recognize it 
my form

```
 <form id="post-form" class="post-form" method="POST" action="answer_submit_process.php">
    <input id="submit-button" type="submit" tabindex="120" name="submitbutton" value="Post Your Answer" />

 </form>
```

and the *answer_submit_process.php* is

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'])){
$userid = $_SESSION['userid']; // i have already started the session
 $selected_ques=  ($_GET['ques']);  
$content =  $_POST["content"] ;

$query="INSERT INTO `formanswer`( `user_id`,`questionid`,`content` )  VALUES ('{$userid}','{$selected_ques}','{$my_html}' ) ";
     $result=mysql_query($query);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickest solution would be saving the value of $_GET['ques'] on a hidden field of the form and thus make it accessible in answer_submit_process.php.

Something like this:

```
 if (isset($_GET['ques'])){
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="ques" value="'.$_GET['ques'].'">';
 }

And in answer_submit_process page the value could easily accessed by $_POST['ques']..
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending via a form POST, then the variable from which you can get data is $_POST instead of $_GET.
Anyway, i wasn´t able to find any field relating to the ques variable on your form, where are they?

Comment: the ques is on the link of page faq_question_sol.php?ques= 62  i want to get this on another page answer_submit_process.php and fro that i am using the above code

Comment: if you dont include your ques variable into the form, it wont be sent into the next script!

Comment: you should add a <input type="hidden" name="ques" value="<?php echo $_GET['ques'] ?>" /> into the form to be able to get the variable to the next script by using the $_POST variable

Answer (score 1):

Add `<input type="hidden" name="ques" value="<?php echo $_GET['ques'] ?>"/>` to your form to temporarily store the variable, and then use the variable `$_POST['ques']` in place of `$_GET['ques']` in the processing page.

Alternatively, you could change the form action to `answer_submit_process.php?ques=<?php echo $_GET['ques']; ?>`.